# DIV breaking out of P tags

Tags: html, grails, gsp

In my Grails app, I have a GSP with the following markup:

```
<p class='foo'>
  <label>Email</label>
  <g:textField id="email" name="email" class="field required email"
      title="Please enter a valid email address" maxlength="50" value="${signUp?.email}"/>
  <g:eachError bean="${signUp}" field="email">
    <div class="fieldError"><g:message error="${it}"/></div>
  </g:eachError>
</p>

<label>Your Age:</label>
```

When the email field has an error, this generates the following HTML:

```
<p class="foo">
  <label style="width: 100px;">Email</label>
  <input id="email" class="field required email" type="text" value="" maxlength="50" title="Please enter a valid email address" name="email" style="width: 275px;">
</p>
<div class="fieldError" style="margin-left: 155px;">No email was provided</div>
<p></p>
<label style="width: 100px; vertical-align:middle;">Your Age:</label>
```

I can't figure out:

- why `<div class="fieldError>` appears outside `<p class='foo'>`
- where is `<p></p>` coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<p>` elements don't allow block level elements inside them, so that's why `<div class="fieldError>` is outside `<p class='foo'>`.

I'm not sure why you have an extra `p` tag below the first one. Can you post the generated HTML when you just use pure HTML?

---

A quick experiment shows that nested block elements mysteriously generate another `<p>` tag in FF6, Chrome 13 and Opera 11.51

This is the typed code:

```
<p>
    P
    <div>
        DIV1
        <div>
            DIV1a
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
```

And this is the output:

```
<p>P</p>
<div>
    DIV1
    <div>
        DIV1a
    </div>
</div>
<p></p>
```

It appears that each block level element (here a `<div>`) is pushed out of any `<p>` tags, and creates another `<p>` tag underneath it.

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-P):

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

Comment: I'm using Firefox 6.0.1. If `<p>` is a block element, then why can't I nest other block elements (like `<div>`) within it?

Comment: @Gaby I thought the nesting rules are the same for all block elements?

Comment: @Don, the nesting rules are defined based on the semantics of each tag and not on wether it is just block or inline.. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values